# Create json file out of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional array that consists of 3 arrays inside. See below my minimum runnable example:

```
<?php

$array1 = array("Bitcoin", "Ethereum", "Bitcoin Cash");
$array2 = array("BTC", "ETH", "BTC");
$array3 = array("10000", "3000", "6666");


//Multi Dimensional Array
$multi = array($array1, $array2, $array3);
print_r($multi);

foreach($multi as $k =>$a){
  $multi[$k] = json_decode(json_encode($a));
}

print_r($multi);

// $json_data = json_encode($multi);
file_put_contents('data/myfile.json', $multi);
```

However, I get the following output in my output file:

```
ArrayArrayArray
```

Any suggestions how to get the data like the following:

```
{
"Bitcoin", 
"BTC", 
"10000"
},
{
"Ethereum", 
"ETH", 
"3000"
},
{
"Bitcoin Cash", 
"BTC", 
"6666"
},
```

Comment: Does all three arrays always contain the same amount of items as each other?

Comment: Btw, the json you want is invalid. `{}` are for objects `{ key: 'value', key2: 'value2', ... }` while `[]` is for arrays `['item1', 'item2', ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your expected result isn't valid json. It should be arrays `[]` instead of `{}`.

Below is how you can format the data like you want it.
However, it assumes that the three arrays always are of equal length:

```
$array1 = array("Bitcoin", "Ethereum", "Bitcoin Cash");
$array2 = array("BTC", "ETH", "BTC");
$array3 = array("10000", "3000", "6666");

$new = [];

// Restructure your array to get one item from each array
foreach ($array1 as $index => $value) {
    $new[] = [
        $value,
        $array2[$index],
        $array3[$index]
    ];
}

$multi = json_encode($new);
```

This would produce the format you want, but in valid json format:

```
[
    [
        "Bitcoin",
        "BTC",
        "10000"
    ],
    [
        "Ethereum",
        "ETH",
        "3000"
    ],
    [
        "Bitcoin Cash",
        "BTC",
        "6666"
    ]
]
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/39kuA

Answer (score 1):

```
{
"Bitcoin", 
"BTC", 
"10000"
},
{
"Ethereum", 
"ETH", 
"3000"
},
{
"Bitcoin Cash", 
"BTC", 
"6666"
},
```

Is not valid JSON format. '{' and '}' means that it's map (object), so there must be 'key:value' rows like:

```
{
0: "Bitcoin"
}
```

Proper JSON for array uses '[' and ']'.

---

```
<?php
$array1 = array("Bitcoin", "Ethereum", "Bitcoin Cash");
$array2 = array("BTC", "ETH", "BTC");
$array3 = array("10000", "3000", "6666");

//Multi Dimensional Array
$multi = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $v) {
    $multi[] = [$array1[$key], $array2[$key], $array3[$key]];
}

file_put_contents('data/myfile.json', json_encode($multi));
```

Produces:

```
[["Bitcoin","BTC","10000"],["Ethereum","ETH","3000"],["Bitcoin Cash","BTC","6666"]]
```

Formated:

```
[
    [
        "Bitcoin",
        "BTC",
        "10000"
    ],
    [
        "Ethereum",
        "ETH",
        "3000"
    ],
    [
        "Bitcoin Cash",
        "BTC",
        "6666"
    ]
]
```

Comment: That's not the result the OP is asking for, though.

Comment: Tags are 'php json multidimensional-array', not 'php weird-format miltidimensional-array'. He wanted to format PHP to JSON arrays, so I did that. Updated answer with information about proper format.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I'm 100% game on the invalid json. But look at the data inside. The OP wants to combine the three arrays.

Comment: Ops. Code fixed.